# reportlab install error in django app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, reportlab

I want to install reportlab to make pdf file from python script. But I got the following error.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/remoshindev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/remoshindev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/ubuntu/remoshindev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
  File "/home/ubuntu/remoshindev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 922, in install
with open(inst_files_path, 'w') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './lib/python3.5/site-packages/olefile-0.44-py3.5.egg-info/installed-files.txt'
```

I don't have a "./lib/python3.5/site-packages/olefile-0.44-py3.5.egg-info/installed-files.txt".

How can I fix it? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try after installing `olefile`

```
pip install olefile
```

or if `python3` then

```
pip3 install olefile
```

Comment: Thank you for a reply. I tried to install olefile. But same error was occured.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './lib/python3.5/site-packages/olefile-0.44-py3.5.egg-info/installed-files.txt

Comment: @KazzzStudio, did you try `pip3 install olefile`

Comment: I did makemigrations and migrate. The command for install olefile is the "pip3 install  --install-option="--prefix=."  olefile". but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using virtual environment?

Comment: Yes. I use virtualenv.

Comment: Try global install once `sudo pip3 install olefile` and then if still not works try: `pip3 install pillow` and see if that works.

Comment: I tried `sudo pip3 install olefile` and it works. But I retry to install reportlab, it still occur same error. I can install reportlab when I use sudo, but I want to install reportlab in my virtual environment, because my script couldn't find reportlab if I don't install it in virtual environment. Maybe my environment was broken. I want to fix the problem.

Comment: @KazzzStudio If this solution helped you, please voteup and select the answer. If you still face any problem let me know by comments below.

Comment: I still solve the error. I can install olefile in my global environment using "sudo". But I still couldn't install reportlab. I got the same error.

Comment: I need your help. Please help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156187/discussion-between-astik-anand-and-kazzz-studio).